# How to typecast Bigint into Timestamp in java?

Tags: java

Below code I tried by not working out..

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
    public class TimestampTest {
         public static void main(String[] args){
    long unixSeconds = 1429582984839L; // suffix L 
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(unixSeconds*1000L);

     System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
  }}
```

Expected output:21/04/2015 03:15 AM  in this format.....but I am getting 47271-09-06 09:40:39.0

Comment: Please specify what is not working, what is your expected output, what output are you getting?

Comment: Could you display the error that you are getting? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your number 1429582984839 is already in milliseconds. There is no need to multiply it by 1000. That's all you need to know.

(For anyone who wants to confirm in JavaScript, try: new Date(1429582984839) --> "2015-04-21T02:23:04.839Z")

Comment: hi nayuki..i almost got the out put 2015-04-21 03:15:44.472....but i need          2015-04-21 03:15:44 AM....can u help me out

Answer (score 1):

```
  long unixSeconds = 1429582984839;
   Date date1 = new Date(unixSeconds); 
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"); 
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
   String formattedDate = sdf.format(date1);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a long type variables, you need to suffix 'L' or 'l' in the number. Otherwise it will take it is an integer.

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    public void demoMethod() {
    long unixSeconds = 1333372339860L; // suffix L 
    Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
```

Try this code, It will work. If it is useful or correct. Please mark it useful or correct answer. 
use this code it is much simpler and easier.

```
    import java.sql.TimeStamp;
    long unixSeconds = 1333372339860L; // suffix L 
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(unixSeconds*1000L);
     System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

1333372339860 / 60 /60 /24 / 365 = 42280

Plus 1970 = 44250

So the program is correct (my calculation ignores leap years).

Where did you get the number from ?